# Akka: Should seed node always be running for new nodes to join akka-cluster?

Tags: scala, akka, distributed-computing, akka-cluster

Steps to reproduce problem:

1. Start Seed1 node (First seed mentioned in conf)
2. Start another node(Node2). It will discover seed node and join cluster system.
   // Requests are served by both nodes.
3. Now, Stop Seed1.
   // All Requests are served by Node2.
4. Start another node(Node3). It will start but say that seed nodes are unreachable. 
   // All requests are still served only by Node2. I assume because this node failed to join the cluster.
5. Restart Seed1.
   // Logs show MemberUp logs for Seed1 and Node3, But
   // All requests are still served by Node2!

Comment: Post your application.conf file please

Comment: You should add both seeders to cluster configuration

Comment: Do you need more help/explanation on this question?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation:

> The seed nodes can be started in any order and it is not necessary to have all seed nodes running, but **the node configured as the first element in the seed-nodes configuration list must be started when initially starting a cluster**, otherwise the other seed-nodes will not become initialized and no other node can join the cluster. **Once more than two seed nodes have been started it is no problem to shut down the first seed node**. If the first seed node is restarted, it will first try to join the other seed nodes in the existing cluster.